# The program ends too soon

Tags: c++

I am writing a program where 5 judges enter a score between 0 and 10 and calculates the average after dropping the highest and lowest score. Every time I run the program it calculates the average after putting just one score and stops the program. I don't know what I am doing wrong. How can I make it run where it collects all 5 scores, drops the highest and lowest, and then calculates the average? Here's my code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void getjudgescore(double& judge1, double& judge2, double& judge3, double& judge4, double& judge5)
{
    for (int judge = 1; judge < 6; judge++)
    {
        double j = 0;
        do
        {
            cout << "Judge #" << judge << " - Please enter a score between 0.0 and 10.0 : ";
            cin >> j;
            if (j < 0 || j > 10)
            {
                cout << "Score must be between 0.0 and 10.0 : ";
                cin >> j;
            }
        } while (j < 0 || j > 10);
        switch (judge)
        {
        case 0: if (judge == 1)
        {
            judge1 = j;
            break;
        }
        case 1: if (judge == 2)
        {
            judge2 = j;
            break;
        }
        case 2: if (judge == 3)
        {
            judge3 = j;
            break;
        }
        case 3: if (judge == 4)
        {
            judge4 = j;
            break;
        }
        case 4: if (judge = 5)
        {
            judge5 = j;
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
double findLowest(double& judge1, double& judge2, double& judge3, double& judge4, double& judge5)
{
    double lowest = 10;
    if (lowest > judge1)
    {
        lowest = judge1;
    }
    if (lowest > judge2)
    {
        lowest = judge2;
    }
    if (lowest > judge3)
    {
        lowest = judge3;
    }
    if (lowest > judge4)
    {
        lowest = judge4;
    }
    if (lowest = judge5)
    {
        lowest = judge5;
    }
    return lowest;
}
double findHighest(double& judge1, double& judge2, double& judge3, double& judge4, double& judge5)
{
    double highest = 0;
    if (judge1 > highest)
    {
        highest = judge1;
    }
    if (judge2 > highest)
    {
        highest = judge2;
    }
    if (judge3 > highest)
    {
        highest = judge3;
    }
    if (judge4 > highest)
    {
        highest = judge5;
    }
    return highest;
}
double calcScore(double& judge1, double& judge2, double& judge3, double& judge4, double& judge5, double& highest, double& lowest)
{
    double total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    total = judge1 + judge2 + judge3 + judge4 + judge5;
    total = total - highest - lowest;
    average = total / 3;
    cout << "Final Score : " << average;
    return average;
}
int main()
{
    double judge1 = 0, judge2 = 0, judge3 = 0, judge4 = 0, judge5 = 0;
    double totalscore = 0;
    double highscore = 0;
    double lowscore = 0;
    double highest = 0;
    double lowest = 0;
    getjudgescore(judge1, judge2, judge3, judge4, judge5);
    findLowest(judge1, judge2, judge3, judge4, judge5);
    findLowest(judge1, judge2, judge3, judge4, judge5);
    calcScore(judge1, judge2, judge3, judge4, judge5, highest, lowest);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: They say there's three common problems in software development: Naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: I think it's time to learn how to use arrays, as this becomes trivial if you had simply declared `int judge[5];` and not 5 separate variables.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That would not actually fix his code directly... You have a good point though, if his code was re-written with an array or (better) a vector of doubles in mind, not only could the switch be avoided, but the entire input method could be generalized to accept an arbitrary number of judges.

Comment: I explain why your code stops too early and I given a simplified version of your code using vector, as you can see the code become short and simple, its size is independent of the number of judges, see my answer

Answer (score -1):

It's the if statements in your switch, they're all offset by one.

In

```
switch(judge)
{
    case 0: if (judge == 1)
    {
        judge1 = j;
        break;
    }
```

The if will never evaluate true, as when the case is valid, `judge` is 0.

Additionally, the if statements in the switch are redundant.